# Where is the verse where Krishna says he's the father of all?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, reference-request

While reading Srila Prabhupada's introduction to the Bhagavad Gita I came across him saying that Krishna himself says he is the father of all. So where is this verse located within the Bhagavad Gita?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/14/verse/3-4

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 14, Verse 3-4

> मम योनिर्महद् ब्रह्म तस्मिन्गर्भं दधाम्यहम् |
> सम्भव: सर्वभूतानां ततो भवति भारत || 3||
> सर्वयोनिषु कौन्तेय मूर्तय: सम्भवन्ति या: |
> तासां ब्रह्म महद्योनिरहं बीजप्रद: पिता || 4||

> BG 14.3-4: The total material substance, prakṛiti, is the womb. I impregnate it with the individual souls, and thus all living beings are born. O son of Kunti, for all species of life that are produced, the material nature is the womb, and I am the seed-giving Father.